# How to get only one secret value from one secret key using the AWS plug in "AWS Secrets Manager- Get Secret" in Azure DevOps/Pipeline/Release

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, aws-secrets-manager

In Azure DevOps/Pipeline/Release I am using the AWS plug in "AWS Secrets Manager- Get Secret".

In My AWS secret I have the secret name and in that I have two secret keys with values.

Using the AWS plug in "AWS Secrets Manager- Get Secret" is there any way to pull out the value for just one of the keys?

Say for instance that I only want to get the secret value of the "db_pw" key using the plug in and assign that to the Azure variable password "DB_password".

I understand that I can just point the plug in it to the secret "TVS_Live" but it puts the two keys I have in the secret in the ADO variable "DB_password" and then I have to later parse it all out using something like jq.

I just want to pull the secret value of one secret key out - "db_pw" - resulting in me getting "" in the Azure DevOps variable "DB_Password" (see images below)

Is there a way to do this?

Here is my ADO AWS secret plug in configuration (which now pulls in everything) :
[image]

Here is my AWS secret configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the task [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/secretsmanager-getsecret.html) description, this should be by design.

> Use this task to **retrieve the value of a secret** stored in AWS Secrets
> Manager and store it locally in an Azure DevOps build variable. The
> build variable will be automatically set to 'secret' mode to
> automatically mask the value when logged or otherwise displayed.

To achieve your needs, you could need to split secret keys into separate Secrets to obtain the value of a single secret key. You can submit a [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/issues?utm_source=vsmp&utm_medium=ms%20web&utm_campaign=mpdetails) to this task on github.

Comment: That is what I figured needed to happen. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @ErnieAndBert, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it [as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks

Comment: @ErnieAndBert, any update about this issue, if you have any other concern about this issue, please feel free to let us know. If this answer is helpful, please consider to [accept it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png).